# How can I add a new bulk action to the bulk action dropdown field in the comments interface

Tags: comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom bulk_action](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29822/custom-bulk-action)

As the title suggests I would like to  add a new bulk action to the bulk action dropdown field in the comments interface. Specifically, I would like to add a CSS class to specific comments on the front end by marking comments with this new bulk action.