# Custom bulk actions in WP 3.7.1

Tags: actions, bulk

So I am trying to get a custom bulk action to work in Wordpress 3.7.1 and so far no luck. The basis I am using is http://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-custom-bulk-action, and it goes wrong here:

```
$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');
$action = $wp_list_table->current_action();
```

The action itself is added with jQuery and does show.

When I use a prompt to show the `$action` value it is always empty, which means the rest of the script does not fire. Any idea here? The entire code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: FoxRunSoftware Custom Bulk Action Demo
Plugin URI: http://www.foxrunsoftware.net/articles/wordpress/add-custom-bulk-action/
Description: A working demonstration of a custom bulk action
Author: Justin Stern
Author URI: http://www.foxrunsoftware.net
Version: 0.1

Copyright: © 2012 Justin Stern (email : justin@foxrunsoftware.net)
License: GNU General Public License v3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
*/

if (!class_exists('FRS_Custom_Bulk_Action')) {

    class FRS_Custom_Bulk_Action {

        public function __construct() {

            if(is_admin()) {
                // admin actions/filters
                add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', array(&$this, 'custom_bulk_admin_footer'));
                add_action('load-edit.php',         array(&$this,     'custom_bulk_action'));
            add_action('admin_notices',         array(&$this, 'custom_bulk_admin_notices'));
        }
    }


    /**
     * Step 1: add the custom Bulk Action to the select menus
     */
    function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {
        global $post_type;

        if($post_type == 'post') {
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery('<option>').val('export').text('<?php _e('Export')?>').appendTo("select[name='action']");
                        jQuery('<option>').val('export').text('<?php _e('Export')?>').appendTo("select[name='action2']");
                    });
                </script>
            <?php
        }
    }


    /**
     * Step 2: handle the custom Bulk Action
     * 
     * Based on the post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29822/custom-bulk-action
     */
    function custom_bulk_action() {
        global $typenow;
        $post_type = $typenow;

        if($post_type == 'post') {

            // get the action
            $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');  // depending on your resource type this could be WP_Users_List_Table, WP_Comments_List_Table, etc
            $action = $wp_list_table->current_action();

            $allowed_actions = array("export");
            if(!in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) return;

            // security check
            check_admin_referer('bulk-posts');

            // make sure ids are submitted.  depending on the resource type, this may be 'media' or 'ids'
            if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])) {
                $post_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['post']);
            }

            if(empty($post_ids)) return;

            // this is based on wp-admin/edit.php
            $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('exported', 'untrashed', 'deleted', 'ids'), wp_get_referer() );
            if ( ! $sendback )
                $sendback = admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=$post_type" );

            $pagenum = $wp_list_table->get_pagenum();
            $sendback = add_query_arg( 'paged', $pagenum, $sendback );

            switch($action) {
                case 'export':

                    // if we set up user permissions/capabilities, the code might look like:
                    //if ( !current_user_can($post_type_object->cap->export_post, $post_id) )
                    //  wp_die( __('You are not allowed to export this post.') );

                    $exported = 0;
                    foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {

                        if ( !$this->perform_export($post_id) )
                            wp_die( __('Error exporting post.') );

                        $exported++;
                    }

                    $sendback = add_query_arg( array('exported' => $exported, 'ids' => join(',', $post_ids) ), $sendback );
                break;

                default: return;
            }

            $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('action', 'action2', 'tags_input', 'post_author', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', '_status',  'post', 'bulk_edit', 'post_view'), $sendback );

            wp_redirect($sendback);
            exit();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Step 3: display an admin notice on the Posts page after exporting
     */
    function custom_bulk_admin_notices() {
        global $post_type, $pagenow;

        if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'post' && isset($_REQUEST['exported']) && (int) $_REQUEST['exported']) {
            $message = sprintf( _n( 'Post exported.', '%s posts exported.', $_REQUEST['exported'] ), number_format_i18n( $_REQUEST['exported'] ) );
            echo "<div class=\"updated\"><p>{$message}</p></div>";
        }
    }

    function perform_export($post_id) {
        // do whatever work needs to be done
        return true;
    }
}
}

new FRS_Custom_Bulk_Action();
```

Well there is some more info, it seems to me that WP_List_Table just returns empty values. The following is the content of $wp_list_table, any ideas?:

```
object(WP_Posts_List_Table)#8848 (10) { 
    ["hierarchical_display"]=> NULL 
    ["comment_pending_count"]=> NULL 
    ["user_posts_count"]=> NULL 
    ["sticky_posts_count"]=> int(0) 
    ["items"]=> NULL 
    ["_args"]=> array(4) { 
        ["plural"]=> string(5) "posts" 
        ["singular"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["ajax"]=> bool(false) 
        ["screen"]=> object(WP_Screen)#8846 (16) { 
            ["action"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["base"]=> string(4) "edit" 
            ["columns":"WP_Screen":private]=> int(0) 
            ["id"]=> string(15) "edit-shop_order" 
            ["in_admin":protected]=> string(4) "site" 
            ["is_network"]=> bool(false) 
            ["is_user"]=> bool(false) 
            ["parent_base"]=> NULL 
            ["parent_file"]=> NULL 
            ["post_type"]=> string(10) "shop_order" 
            ["taxonomy"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["_help_tabs":"WP_Screen":private]=> array(0) { } 
            ["_help_sidebar":"WP_Screen":private]=> string(0) "" 
            ["_options":"WP_Screen":private]=> array(0) { } 
            ["_show_screen_options":"WP_Screen":private]=> NULL 
            ["_screen_settings":"WP_Screen":private]=> NULL 
        } 
    } 
    ["_pagination_args"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["screen"]=> object(WP_Screen)#8846 (16) { 
        ["action"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["base"]=> string(4) "edit" 
        ["columns":"WP_Screen":private]=> int(0) 
        ["id"]=> string(15) "edit-shop_order" 
        ["in_admin":protected]=> string(4) "site" 
        ["is_network"]=> bool(false) 
        ["is_user"]=> bool(false) 
        ["parent_base"]=> NULL 
        ["parent_file"]=> NULL 
        ["post_type"]=> string(10) "shop_order" 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["_help_tabs":"WP_Screen":private]=> array(0) { } 
        ["_help_sidebar":"WP_Screen":private]=> string(0) "" 
        ["_options":"WP_Screen":private]=> array(0) { } 
        ["_show_screen_options":"WP_Screen":private]=> NULL 
        ["_screen_settings":"WP_Screen":private]=> NULL 
    } 
    ["_actions"]=> NULL ["_pagination"]=> NULL 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing `$action` empty because there is a redirect from `wp-admin/edit.php`.

So, the output you are seeing is after the redirect.

Use, `die()` after `echo $action` to see the output before the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page you've mentioned, I note that there's a code snippet that's missing some code.  In the first code snippet after **The Solution**, there's the following code snippet:

```
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', 'custom_bulk_admin_footer');

function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {

  global $post_type;

  if($post_type == 'post') {

    ?>
```

Then the author states *As you can see, here we use javascript to inject our new bulk action item into the two bulk action select dropdowns on the Posts edit page*. Only... there's no javascript in that code snippet.

Looking at the page's source, though, I find this:

```
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', 'custom_bulk_admin_footer');



function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {

  global $post_type;

  if($post_type == 'post') {

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('<option>').val('export').text('<?php _e('Export')?>').appendTo("select[name='action']");

        jQuery('<option>').val('export').text('<?php _e('Export')?>').appendTo("select[name='action2']");

      });

    </script>

    <?php

  }

}
```

...which actually *does* include the JS code (though not in the way you should do it in WordPress -- see [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more on that.

Comment: Actually the options do appear in the bulk action drop down, but that's about it. The issue is with current_action() being empty.