# woocommerce add a new bulk action in the bulk actions dropdown in the orders list

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, bulk

I'm trying to add a custom bulk action in the WooCommerce orders list that will a piece of code I've made for individual orders but need to make it work recursively.

I'm aware of that: [Custom bulk_action](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29822/custom-bulk-action) but it is referring to wordpress bulk action menus and not specifically for woocommerce.

could you please help me get it working in my plugin for woocommerce orders list?

Furthermore, I'm also a bit stuck about how, after adding that action, to scan which orders are checked and apply the bulk action only on the selected orders.

Comment: The user LoicTheAztec responded to a similar question on SO. You should look at his answer because it could help you to solve your problem. [Using custom bulk actions on admin orders list in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562272/using-custom-bulk-actions-on-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: Thank you. That question helped me and I made the plugin work as I mentioned in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LoicTheAztec commented, the post here [Using custom bulk actions on admin orders list in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562272/using-custom-bulk-actions-on-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce-3) helped me to make the code for my plugin. Although it mentions that you should use the functions.php to make it work, I was able to implement it perfectly in my own plugin code.

Thanks, Loic. I appreciate it.